# Unable to install MAAS directly using DVD

Tags: system-installation, maas

Unable to install MAAS directly using DVD. Getting POSTGRE database error.

[image: img]

Comment: You need to give more information. Did you comply to the requirements?
"You will need one small server for MAAS and at least one server which can be managed with a BMC. It is recommended to have the MAAS server provide DHCP and DNS on a network the managed machines are connected to.".

Comment: Way to help @WillemK.  Have you tried to build a MaaS server off the iso?

Comment: @mustakos: Are you asking me if i installed MaaS? No, i did not. Not sure its helpfull if i did?

Comment: It is what would have addressed Vamsi's problem.
You answered without understanding what was going on, though he stated it plainly.  He used the iso, selected install maas server, and the install failed. The only things required to install maas are a machine with a dvd drive and a dvd. To do more, you either need more machines or VMS,  But for installing, you only need one machine.

Answer (score 0):

I get this same error every time I try to build a maas server off the 16.04 iso.

I select **Install Ubuntu Server** and in **Software selection** I choose **PostgreSQL database** and **openSSH server**

After the system builds, at the command line, I use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maas
reboot
```

At that point I think you are in the same place you would be if you selected installed MaaS directly from the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly the same you did and it works! you don't have to install  PostgreSQL database, just openssh.
sudo apt install maas will do the job for you.
after the install is done, create a user for the webGUI , you can find how to in the guides.
after that just open a web browser pointing that MAAS url and done!

Comment: This is in as an error on launchpad, so they may have fixed it